# Why in ConcurrentHashMap does JDK 8 introduce CounterCell to solve the problem of counting?

Tags: java, java-8

The question is about java8.

Why does JDK 8 introduce CounterCell to solve the problem of counting rather than using CAS to increment baseCount simply or using AtomicInteter directly?

And to understand it really makes me feel depressed.... i can't figure out many  if-else block about what it means or handles. could you please give me some advice of reading and understanding it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: CAS == Compare And Swap ? And I couldn't find anything about **JDKer**. What is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in contended environments a `LongAdder` (that `CounterCell` is based on) - is [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47801514/1059372). In general, if you want to understand *how* that is faster - you need to understand what `AtomicInteger` and what `LongAdder` do. And they handle things differently when a single `CAS` fails.